# how to work with bing map rest api to find a location

Tags: bing-maps

When I wrote any location like "Surat","mumbai", etc it will display its location on map using Bing Map Rest API but when i write "Jamnagar Reliance" it will not give any result
i search location using "location by query" api.

```
http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?q=
```

I am using above url to find a location.
It returns following result

```
{"authenticationResultCode":"ValidCredentials","brandLogoUri":"http:\/\/dev.virtualearth.net\/Branding\/logo_powered_by.png","copyright":"Copyright © 2015 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.","resourceSets":[{"estimatedTotal":0,"resources":[]}],"statusCode":200,"statusDescription":"OK","traceId":"a9a6612f91ad4d26af8782a71568b1e2|HK20271656|02.00.108.1000|HK2SCH010280621, HK2SCH010310228, HK2SCH010301656, i-98935154.ap-southeast-1a, CO3SCH010265312"}
```

Comment: 'Jamnagar Reliance' is not a place, so the string that you're trying to geocode won't return any good result. 'Jamnagar' alone should return something, but not 'Reliance' since it's a brand.

Comment: Which API i have to use to find same mentioned above?

Comment: It might be interesting to take a look at Bing Search API, but it will be related to the data coverage in India, see: https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/search

Answer (score 0):

Bing Maps actually finds Reliance, India when you search for Jamnagar Reliance. If no results are being returned you should also check the header of the response. Trial and Basic Bing Maps keys are rate limited to ensure that non-licensed users do not distribute the service for licensed users. You can find the documentation on rate limiting here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701703.aspx